# Camera in Kivy with OpenCV takes a lot of time to load

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, kivymd

The title says it all, the loading of camera video takes a lot of time and stays in "Not Responding" at that time.
It takes almost 1 to 2 minutes to load the camera.

This is my code.

```py
class Attendance(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):

        self.image = Image()

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0/30.0)

        self.add_widget(self.image)

        return super().on_enter(*args)

    def load_video(self, *args):
        frame = self.capture.read()
        self.iamge_frame = frame

        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt = 'ubyte')

        self.image.texture = texture
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how many cameras have you attached to your computer?

Comment: there is only 1 camera attached to my computer. but there is another virtual camera. the obs virtual camera. @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: i have now disabled obs virtual camera. and only 1 camera remains. But still the video loading takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing `self.capture` to the following:

```py
self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```